# How I can empty span in html content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need empty a span content, I try use that:

```
        $(function() {
            var x = $(".carrinho span").empty();

        });
```

```
<div class="carrinho">
                    <a href="http://localhost/loja/shopping_cart.php">
                    <span>Carrinho </span>
                    <strong>0 </strong>produto</a>
</div>
```

I had use that code and work for me guys!

```
cartHtml = $('.meu_carrinho a').html().split('produto')[0];
$('.meu_carrinho a').html(cartHtml);
```

So the expected result is

```html
<div class="carrinho">
  <a href="http://localhost/loja/shopping_cart.php">
    <span></span>
    <strong>0 </strong>produto
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks bros!

Comment: have you tried with something like   var x = $(".carrinho span").html('');   ?

Comment: I have added the expected result (as your question stands) to your question. Please check if that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple using vanilla Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // same as $(document).ready(function() {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.carrinho span');
  for (const span of spans) {
    span.textContent = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="carrinho">
  <a href="http://localhost/loja/shopping_cart.php">
    <span>Carrinho </span>
    <strong>0 </strong>produto</a>
</div>
<div class="carrinho">
  <a href="http://localhost/loja/shopping_cart.php">
    <span>Carrinho </span>
    <strong>0 </strong>produto</a>
</div>
<div class="carrinho">
  <a href="http://localhost/loja/shopping_cart.php">
    <span>Carrinho </span>
    <strong>0 </strong>produto</a>
</div>
<div class="carrinho">
  <a href="http://localhost/loja/shopping_cart.php">
    <span>Carrinho </span>
    <strong>0 </strong>produto</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I try that but dont work
i did like this:
```
  $(function() {
   const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.carrinho span');
   for (const span of spans) { span.textContent = ''; }
  });
```
do i need to do something else?

Comment: No, that should work, unless you're trying it in any IE version. Notice that you don't need any jQuery here, updating my answer to wrap the code so it's only executed once the DOM is parsed.

Comment: But work using that code:
```
cartHtml = $('.meu_carrinho a').html().split('produto')[0];
$('.meu_carrinho a').html(cartHtml);
```

Comment: @Piloni The result of that is definitely not what you asked for in your question. You asked for how to empty the span elements.

Comment: You're right, I could not express myself and I believe that the way I did it worked visually, because it kept the word, but solved what I needed, thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 2):

Try like:

```
var x = $(".carrinho span").html('');
```

Comment: i try but dont work
```
  $(function() {
   var x = $(".carrinho span").html('');

  });
```
I code that corretly?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `html('')` not 'empty()'.

```
  $(function() {
        var x = $(".carrinho span").html('');
    });
```